# Magento Cart Template Update Not work when first visit a page

Tags: php, magento

I want to override the exist cart template since I add some module in it. I use the XML below to update the layout.

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="checkout.cart">
        <action method="setCartTemplate">
            <value>magefd/shipandpay/checkout/cart.phtml</value>
        </action>
        <action method="setEmptyTemplate">
            <value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value>
        </action>
        <action method="chooseTemplate"/>
        <block type="fdshipandpay/checkout_cart_fee" name="magefd.shipandpay.cart.fee"
            as="fee" template="magefd/shipandpay/checkout/cart/fee.phtml" />
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

However, the original template will be used when a new user visit the cart at first time. After they refresh, it work perfect. After session time out if the user refresh it, the same problem comes out. I don't know how it happened. Any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy your .phtml file to all templates directories..eg, Default, and Base theme..Clean cache and try again..

Comment: That leads to duplicate code, and duplicate efforts when updating it -- if the goal was to use the same template everywhere.

Comment: @MihaiStancu  I thought he used 2 templates for his shop..He mentioned like original template ..I just confused now..

Comment: I want to update some layout only. In fact I got this solve. It cause because a submodule declare wrongly so not every time the template layout work. Thx for answering.